# Como calcular a porcentagem de NA em um data frame no R?

Tags: r

Olá,

Estou trabalhando com um data frame grande - 1000 variáveis e 60 mil linhas - e preciso calcular a porcentagem de NA e de espaços em branco para cada uma das variáveis separadamente.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso no R?

Answer (score 3):

Para contar `NA` por colunas pode-se usar a função `colSums()`:

```
# total de linhas
n = nrow(df)

# porcentagem de NA por coluna
round(colSums(is.na(df))*100/n, 2)
```

Ou também pode-se usar a função `apply()`:

```
# função para contar NA's
sum_NA <- function(dados){
  sum(is.na(dados))
}

# total de linhas
n = nrow(df)

# aplicando a função em cada coluna
round(apply(df, 2, sum_NA)*100/n, 2)
```

Comment: Proporção de NA por coluna: `colMeans(is.na(df))`. (Para porcentagem deveria multiplicar por 100.)

Comment: Exatamente, acabei me esquecendo desse detalhe.

Comment: Muito obrigada, Fernandes e Rui Barradas. Ainda estou engatinhando com o R e a ajuda de vocês foi muito valiosa!

Answer (score 0):

Bom vamos lá, uma das maneiras de se fazer é criar um loop e pegar coluna por coluna do seu data frame.

criei um data frame pra exemplificar

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(NA,2,'',1),B=c('',4,4,2),C=c(5,'','',''),D=c(7,7,5,4),E=c('','',NA,NA),F=c(9,9,0,6))
```

Repara que em alguns deles tem valores em branco e NA...

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    print(sum(is.na(df[,c(i)]   )   | df[,c(i)] == ""  )/length(df[,c(i)]) * 100)
}
```

Esse é um loop que anda em cada coluna e calcula a porcentagem que você precisa,  baseado no meu data frame esse `for` vai imprimir os seguintes resultados:

```
[1] 50
[1] 25
[1] 75
[1] 0
[1] 100
[1] 0
```

quer algo mais simples e que talvez seja mais rápido ? experimente:

```
print(colMeans(is.na(df) | df == "")*100)
```

Isso dá a seguinte saída:

```
  A   B   C   D   E   F 
 50  25  75   0 100   0
```

Olha lá `is.na` é uma função do `R` que encontra todos os `NA's` fiz um `ou(|)` para encontrar todos os vazios  `==""`, eu acho que essa ultima opção seja mais rápida, pois só usa funções compiladas de maneira nativa do `R`

Comment: Daniel e Eder, muito obrigada! Valiosíssima ajuda para quem está começando no R como eu!